# Pandas Linear Regression module issue

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a DataFrame with the following code:

```
    import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

data = pandas.read_csv('cost_revenue_clean_v1.csv')

data.describe()

X = DataFrame(data,columns = ['production_budget_usd'])
y = DataFrame(data, columns = ['worldwide_gross_usd'])

plt.figure(figsize = (10,6))
plt.scatter(X,y, alpha = 0.3)
plt.title('Film cost vs Global Revenue')
plt.xlabel('Production Budget $')
plt.ylabel('Worldwide Gross $')
plt.xlim(0,450000000)
plt.ylim(0,3000000000)
plt.show()

regression = LinearRegression()
regression.fit(X, y)
```

Everything works fine until I add the final line: regression.fit(X, y), at which point I get an error which says:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

What is causing this error, and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. _What is causing this error_ Have you read the error, done any debugging?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove null values in order to make a prediction!

To check if your data contains null values or not?

```
data.isnull()
```

You can Drop null values by:

```
data.dropna()
```

You can also replace null values by a string value 'Missing':

```
data.fillna('Missing')
```